# Hard drive space

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, macosx, macbook-pro

I've recently installed Ubuntu 15.04 alongside my mac osx on my macbook pro.

When I wanted to install, I chose to install it alongside my osx. And then I could divide the partition. So I did 88GB for my Linux and 55 for osx. But now as you can see on my screenshot it's divided? When I'm installing something now like csgo dedicated server is it going to install under my user account or under sda5 ? Can't I merge them? That I have all of those 88gb on my user account?

[image: Screenshot of terminal]

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is a little misleading, because most of those lines *aren't* real partitions.

- The line with filesystem **udev** is a virtual filesystem that does not exist on disk, and just represents some data in memory.
- Lines with filesystem **tmpfs** are virtual filesystems that exist only in memory, or swapped to the existing swap partition.  They are not from actual partitions on the disk.
- The line with filesystem **cgmfs** also appears to be a virtual filesystem related to the cgroups manager which you have for some reason.

That leaves only three lines referring to actual partitions on the drive: partitions `sda5`, `sda2` and `sda3`.

`sda5` contains your entire Ubuntu install, is 69GB and is mounted at `/`.

`sda3` is your Snow Leopard (Mac OS install) which is 55GB and mounted as an add-on drive in `/media/fendora/Snow Leopard`.

`sda2` is another partition which is 19GB and is entitled "LINUX".  I don't know why you have this partition.  It's possible you created it intending for it to be your Linux partition (maybe for a previous Linux install) but you ended up not using it.  It's basically empty.

When you install something in your Ubuntu installation it'll go into that 69GB `sda5` partition.

Comment: Is there a way i can  merge that with the sda5?

Comment: Using gparted (and/or the Ubuntu graphical partition manager, if that's not the same thing), you should be able to delete that `sda2` partition, and then expand your sda5 partition to fill the remaining space.  However, depending on your partition layout, there may be other partitions in between those two, such as your `sda3` (Max OS partition), or a swap partition for Ubuntu, which will make it more complex as I'm not sure if it'll be able to shift those partitions around.

Comment: So, i wen't to reinstall it, but when i choose the partition i made in osx called linux 80gb i choose to format it as ext4 and mount point / and i select the same sda4 as my bootloader. But then when its installed its not booting. I get a blinking _ on a black screen. And when i choose the other options to let ubuntu make the partitions i get the problem i had before.